# NodeJS How to stream screenshots with minimal ms delay?

Tags: node.js, architecture, websocket, video-streaming, webrtc

Here's the setup: I have my personal PC, and I need it to stream screenshots to a server, so that server can stream them to everyone on its website, with minimal ms delay.

Currently I'm piping screenshots to the server multiple times per second using the `request` module's `pipe` feature.

My server isn't allowed to save files, so I store the screenshot in a `buffer`.

The website uses jQuery to refresh the `src` of an `img` on the page multiple times per second, which requests a download of the screenshot from the server. (The server just writes the contents of the buffer and that works fine)

The problem is: This is not very efficient. The delay is ~2 seconds, also the framerate is really bad.

My question is: Can I leverage some cool technologies like `websockets`, `webrtc`, or `long polling` to make this better? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot is possible in webrtc(Only support in chrome) here is  example https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/